# Memory organization in microcontroller

Tags: memory, embedded, microcontroller, memory-segmentation

Is memory in microcontroller organized as Segmented or Flat Model?

I would say it is organized as Flat Model. However, next thing confuse me. Linker creates segmentation parts inside memory (.bss, .text, .data) and reference variables inside this parts using offset address, which is similar to segmented model.

Comment: That would depend entirely on the architecture of the microcontroller - there is not one architecture for _all_ microcontrollers.  Look at the datasheet, reference manual or architecture specification for the part concerned. "Segments" in the context of linker _sections_ .bss, .txt, .data etc. are not at all related to _segments_ in the context of a segmented memory architecture.  It is also more complex that just flat/segmented  memory organisation can be _Von Neumann_ or _Harvard_, and a device may or may not have an MMU or MPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a build chain builds a target consisting of segments of code (.text), 
read-only data, initialized data (.data) and uninitialized data (.bss) it is a piece of cake to merge them to a flat memory model. On the other hand, it is impossible to split up such conglomerate.
As the parts of a build chain usually targeting multiple platforms, they try to keep the segmented architecture as long as possible in the building process.

Microprocessors in computers running on OS’s which employ sophisticated memory management.
In contrast, micro-controllers having a lot of peripheral capabilities and don’t need fences between processes.

Additionally, it depends on your micro-controller whether it follows the Harvard or vonNeumann architecture. 
With the vonNeumann architecture you have finally one, flat, single memory address space.